# Gems suddenly missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku

I'm just learning how to use Ruby on Rails and everything was fine.
But today, as I tried to use the command `rails new foo` or even `rails -v` it gave me this:

```
C:\Users\Me\Ruby>rails new demo_app C:/Program Files
(x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `r
eport_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem railties (>= 0)
(Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems .rb:244:in
`activate_dep'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
```

.rb:236:in
    `activate'
            from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems .rb:1307:in`gem'
            from C:/Ruby193/bin/rails:22:in `'

So... whats going wrong?

`gem list rails` gave me this:

```
C:\Users\Me\Ruby>gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

I'm using Windows 7 and have no rvm or pik, but it worked fine the last 5 days.

Okay, i tried to install rails new with 'gem install rails'
and it said this:

```
C:\Users\Me\Ruby>gem install rails
Fetching: i18n-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.5.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.4.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-cache-1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: journey-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: hike-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: tilt-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: sprockets-2.2.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: arel-3.0.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.35.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: treetop-1.4.12.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.2.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-ssl-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: json-1.7.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Well... i already installed DevKit 5 days ago, but i did it again, this time starting the command line as Admin.

Then i 'tried' to install json:

```
C:\Users\Me\DevKit>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:160: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Program'
Makefile:153: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Program'
Makefile:160: warning: overriding commands for target `Files'
Makefile:153: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Files'
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_generator'"
  > generator-i386-mingw32.def
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPOR
TS', 'Init_generator'"  > generator-i386-mingw32.def'
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/ge
ms/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jso
n-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

And i got this-.-

Im really a beginner in this, so i dont know anything else i could try.

Comment: Might want to check this out for ruby/gem management in windows: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik and here is a way to do gemsets similar to RVM: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/16#issuecomment-3515658

Comment: I added the `windows` tag because it seems like that's your platform (`C:/Program Files (x86)...`)

Answer (score 1):

You probably messed up your ruby/rails installation at some point.

I highly recommend using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) which takes care of installing Ruby, Rails and all the gotchas (DevKit etc) for you, in one click.

Of course you should uninstall everything first.

Answer (score 0):

Well now, i just reinstalled everything, but before doing that i realized that i was in the windows command line. With the git bash i had no problems (ok, not the same, thats why i reinstalled the whole thing). And now everything works fine again.